# How to set path to database in Vb6?

Tags: path, vb6

Using a data control, I connected VB6 program to the database.
In the databasename property of the data control I chose the database file and it set a path like this. "F:\Visual Basic\Assignment2\Access.mdb".

However, in the other computers, it said this is an invalid path. So when I set the path again it became like this."C:\Visual Basic\Assignment2\Access.mdb".

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

The `App.Path` property contains the path of the current EXE (or running project) so if its in the same director as the mdb:

```
dbPath = App.Path & "\Access.mdb"
```